# No window.FB object after loading all.js

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am trying to communicate with the facebook API from a chrome extension (content script).
I tried loading the API through basic javascript or jQuery, as showed on facebook docs.
Current code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fbdiv = jQuery("<div>", {"id": "fb-root"});
    jQuery(document.body).children().first().before(fbdiv);
    $.ajax({
        url: '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js',
        cache: true,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function(a, b, c) {
            console.log("got script");
            console.log(window.FB);
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                console.log("fbAsync called");
                console.log(window.FB);
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Result is that the console.log(window.FB) call returns 'undefined', and the fbAsyncInit function is never called.

The all.js resource is correctly received with response code of 200 or 304. I don't know if the script is correctly evaluated though, as the getScript doc says "The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed." Nevertheless, executing the script should call window.fbAsyncInit(), which never occurs.

Thanks,

Charly

Comment: Why are you reading the documentation for `$.getScript`, and **not** using it ?

Comment: I used the ajax call so I can switch on script caching for this request only. .getScript is a small wrapper around .ajax

Comment: And what is `thisCommenter` ?

Comment: I edited the question to show it to you. It is a reference to my 'class' instance.

Comment: the initFacebook() function is defined elsewhere and never gets called with the above piece of code.

Comment: I've tested the ajax call, and it seems to work just fine, but thisCommenter is undefined, and if you have a custom object defined elsewhere that isn't working, it would be a good idea to add that to the question, as that seems to be the issue ?

Comment: I edited the code to remove any external reference. With this example,  i get in the console output the lines "got script" and "undefined". That's all.

Comment: Content scripts are executed in isolated environement in chrome. The window element accessed in the content script context in not the same as the one accessed in the page context, such as from the all.js script.

The solution was to inject my script into the page as well.